# Erro na url em php

Tags: php

Tenho uma `querystring` para trabalhar com `url`.

```
set_include_path('application' . PATH_SEPARATOR. get_include_path() );

            function getGet( $key ){
                    return isset( $_GET[ $key ] ) ? $_GET[ $key ] : null;
            }
                    $path = ('application');
                    $exe = getGet('exe');
                    if( is_file( ''.$path.'/'.$exe.'.php' ) )
                            include ''.$path.'/'.$exe.'.php';
                    else
                            include ''.$path.'/dash/404.php';
```

Porém estou passando `id` pelas `url`, para gerar novas páginas e tenho uma `div` de erro oculta assim.

```
echo $exibir ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Quando passo para a `url` o erro desta forma:

```
if (!isset($_GET["error"]) == "error") {
    $exibir = null;
} else {
    $exibir = "block";
    //var_dump($nome);
}
```

Então no retorno tenho este:

```
 header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?error=error');
```

Se der erro passa para `url` o error = error então minha `query` fica

```
?id=teste?error=error
```

Porém retorna em branco a tela e não exibe a mensagem de erro. Quando não passo 
o `ID` pela `url` ou crio uma `ID`no caso link, funciona tranquilo, mas dentro da `query` não funciona.

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema. Já agora esse link está errado, devia ser `?id=teste&error=error`.

Comment: O erro está que já tenho uma query na url ?id=teste onde é o ID criado quando passo ?error=error, ficando ?id=teste?error=error a tela fica branca e não executa o `code`echo $exibir ? 'block' : 'none';`code`

Comment: @JorgeB. é que a IF dele está errada: `!isset($_GET["error"]) == "error"`, está comparando um booleano com `== "error"`. "Erro de digitação"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro parâmetro da URL tem que ser passado com `?` (interrogação) os demais são passados com `&` (e comercial).

Exemplo:

> www.algumacoisa.com.br/index.php?param1=4&param2=9&param3=999&param4=etc...

Esse if também tem problema:

```
if (!isset($_GET["error"]) == "error") {
    $exibir = null;
} else {
    $exibir = "block";
    //var_dump($nome);
}
```

Deveria ser algo assim:

```
if (isset($_GET["error"]) && $_GET["error"] === "error") {
    $exibir = null;
} else {
    $exibir = "block";
    //var_dump($nome);
}
```

Comment: Isto continua errado: `if (!isset($_GET["error"]) && $_GET["error"] === "error")`, deveria ser `if (isset($_GET["error"]) && $_GET["error"] === "error")` ... Por falar nisso o `===` nem tem necessidade ai, o `==` já resolve, afinal não está checando números (ou diferenciar do "possiveis" "booleanos") e se for alguma suposta micro-otimização, não vai ter vantagens, é mito ... só funciona se forem muitos dados mesmo.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento, sim, valeu já estava corrigindo quando comentou.

Comment: Amigo obrigado, alterei o header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?error=error'); para header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'&error=error'); funcionou corretamente, poxa estava a dois dias já quebrando minha cabeça, quase refazendo o sistema para trabalhar com banco de dados, Obrigado que deus te abençoe!